# sort NSArray alphabetically, but local language should be first and then all other

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, sorting

I need to sort my array `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` on next rules: first sort using local alphabetic (german, france or some else - current user interface) and then english sort and at the end all other symbols in section #.
I'm tried to make this using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)` method, but they don't help (the sort english first and then local strings). How to do this?

Comment: Figuring out the language is going to be tricky unless you have this stored somewhere....

Comment: It is possible for languages using different character sets, but languages with the same character set will require either a dictionary or an externally set language identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure any of the standard comparators will do what you're asking for, but you can always write your own.

(And if you don't want to have to make a category on `NSString` for implementing your own comparison selector, you can always use `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]` which lets you pass a block.)